# If I set theme of activity so the popup of that activity should not change ,Is this possible?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-alertdialog

While launching my app the blank screen is appear, for resolving this theme has been set to `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"`

But alert dialog of this activity also get change.
I don't want to change the theme of dialogues. 
How can I do that?

Comment: For that you can use different style for `AlertDialog`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a default theme create the dialog like this:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(this, android.R.style.Theme_Dialog));
```

If you want to make further changes to the `Dialog` create a custom style in your xml

```
<style name="CustomDialog" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Dialog">
   // insert your custom attributes
</style>
```

Then the creation of the dialog would be:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(this,R.style.CustomDialog));
```

You can use the style in `DialogFragment`s as well using `setStyle(STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.CustomDialog);` inside `onCreate`